# How can I downgrade from 2012 R2 Standard to 2008 R2 Enterprise?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2, downgrade

What are the actual steps of downgrading from 2012 R2 to 2008 R2? I'm finding plenty of information on how the licensing works for that, and I understand it all, but can't seem to find any information on the actual downgrade process.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are [downgrade rights](https://www.microsoft.com/OEM/en/licensing/sblicensing/Pages/downgrade_rights.aspx#fbid=WwBF4fLilHf), but not a downgrade path. In other words, wipe and reinstall.

Comment: Well, that's probably why I couldn't find any information on downgrading. Thanks

Comment: Has there *ever* really been a downgrade path from a newer version of Windows back to an older release?

Comment: @AndrewMedico : I believe the answer is: Yes.  There was a Windows 3.11 to 3.1 downgrade, which was useful for the "OS/2 for Windows" version of the OS/2 2.1 release, which didn't initially work for Windows 3.11.  The downgrade was made by Microsoft, likely due to some sort of contract with IBM.

Comment: @AndrewMedico Does [the downgrade from Windows 10 to Windows 7/8](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/going-back-to-windows-7-or-windows-81) count?

Comment: @duskwuff That's not _really_ a downgrade in this sense; rather, the previous version of Windows is backed up, and the "downgrade" restores the backup.